# Generalizing the sum for the binomial expansion of a number with negative exponent

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, binomial-theorem, negative-binomial, derivation-of-formulae

It is known that

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{z+n-1}{n}(-1)^{n}x^{n} = (1+x)^{-z},  $$

but what about sums of the form $$ \sum_{n=t}^{\infty} \binom{z+n-1}{n}(-1)^{n}x^{n}?  $$

Is there an explicit formula for them? Notice that shifting the iterator by applying $n=n+t$ will not help because then one will have $n+t$ as the second binomial argument which does not let one apply the sum formula from above. Furthermore, notice that $$ \binom{z+n-1+t}{n+t} = \binom{z+n-1}{n}\frac{z+n-1+1}{n+1}\frac{z+n-1+2}{n+2}...\frac{z+n-1+t}{n+t}. $$ This might be useful but I do not see how to apply it if it is so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sum is [hypergeometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function), so there's actually a computer program which will either find you a closed form in terms of (generalized) hypergeometric functions or will tell you no such closed form exists. See the book [A=B](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/%7Ewilf/AeqB.html) (which is freely available at that link) for a description of this and similar algorithms.

The computer algebra system [sage](https://sagemath.org) has this algorithm built in, so we can ask if a closed form exists. The answer is "yes", but it's nowhere near as nice as you might like. I suspect there's nothing better, though.

```
sage: sum(binom(z+n-1, n) * (-1)^n * x^n, n, t, oo)
(-1)^t*x^t*binomial(t + z - 1, t)*hypergeometric((1, t + z), (t + 1,), -x)
```

In latex, we see your sum is

$$(-x)^{t} {z + t - 1 \choose t} \,_2F_1\left(\begin{matrix} 1,t + z \\ t + 1 \end{matrix} ; -x \right)$$

where ${}_2 F_1$ is probably the best studied hypergeometric function (indeed, it's the original hypergometric function that the others are generalizing, and has been studied since at least Gauss). See [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunction.html) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function) for starting points regarding the known identities, asymptotics, etc. for ${}_2 F_1$.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: $\,_2\text F_1(1,a;b;z)$ is an incomplete beta function. See [here](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/03/06/03/0006/)

Comment: Thank you for linking the book.

Answer (score 2):

There is unfortunately no simple closed form that can be expressed purely with binomials. However, a "closed form" exists using the hypergeometric function.

Recall that the hypergeometric function ${}_2F_1\left(\alpha,\beta;\gamma; x\right)$ is defined as

$${}_2F_1\left(\alpha,\beta;\gamma;x\right)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac {(\alpha)_k (\beta)_k}{(\gamma)_k}\frac {x^k}{k!}$$

Where $(\alpha)_k$ is the pochhammer symbol and can be expressed in terms of the gamma function as

$$(\alpha)_k=\frac {\Gamma(\alpha+k)}{\Gamma(k)}$$

To express our sum in terms of ${}_2F_1$, it's necessary to first apply a shift on the index. I've rewritten the sum with $k$ as the indexing variable, i.e.,

$$S\equiv\sum\limits_{k=n}^{+\infty}\binom {z+k-1}k (-x)^k$$

Replace $k$ with $k+n$ such that the new index starts from $k=0$. Next, express the binomial coefficient in terms of the gamma function since

$$\binom {n}{k}=\frac {\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(k+1)\Gamma(n-k+1)}$$

The sum becomes

$$\begin{align*}S & =(-x)^n\frac {\Gamma(z+n)}{\Gamma(n+1)}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{+\infty}\color{red}{\frac {\Gamma(z+n+k)}{\Gamma(z+n)}}\color{blue}{\frac {\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(n+k+1)}}\frac {\color{brown}{\Gamma(k+1)}}{\Gamma(z)}\frac {(-x)^k}{k!}\end{align*}$$

The colored components can all be expressed in terms of the pochhammer notation giving

$$\begin{align*}\sum\limits_{k=n}^{+\infty}\binom {z+k-1}k(-x)^k & =(-x)^n\binom {z+n-1}n\sum\limits_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac {\color{red}{(z+n)_k}\color{brown}{(1)_k}}{\color{blue}{(n+1)_k}}\frac {(-x)^k}{k!}\\ & =(-x)^n\binom {z+n-1}n {}_2F_1(z+n,1;n+1;-x)\end{align*}$$

Comment: The definition of pochhammer symbol  that you are using is incorrect, it should be $$(\alpha)_k = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+k)}{\Gamma(\alpha)}. $$ I am surprised that it went unnoticed for such a long time.

Comment: @Sam I assume everybody else that saw this answer assumed it was a typo, the final result should still be correct (probably).